# crtexe.c - Issue about debugging C/C++ files in VSCode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

[image]

While debugging C/C++ files with Visual Studio Code, the program flow enters to crtexe.c when press 'step over' or 'step into' key from the line with '}' of main function.

[image]

However, when continue debugging in crtexe.c, the flow just stops at `if (!managedapp)` line and doesn't go back to main() function.

If I press 'step out' key in the line '}' of main(), then a error message **"Unable to step out. Operation failed with error code 0x80004004"** comes out.

I tested same code in another IDE, like CLion or NetBeans, but these issues aren't occurred.

I'm using MinGW-w64 GCC and GDB. How to I resolve this issue?

**Sample Code(main.c):**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Call main()\n");

    int num1 = 1;
    int num2 = 20;
    int num3 = num1 + num2;

    printf("%d\n", num3);

    return 0;
}
```

**launch.json:**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "GDB Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "C:/Users/.../main.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "C:/Users/...",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/msys2/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe",
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/c/": "C:/"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to step into code below `main`.  Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @StephenNewell Debugging session is terminated normally even though I try to step into below `main()` in other IDEs. So I wonder why is it impossible in VSCode.

Comment: If you use gdb directly, without VSCode, do you see the same behavior?

Comment: Your code looks like C program. The C `main` declared improperly. Depending on call convention the stack frame may be corrupted after main exited.

Comment: Use "run" instead?  There's nowhere to go after `main` returns.  Why do you think it should get back into `main` once you get into the library implementation of the program termination code?

Comment: As a result of checking with gdb directly, the debugging session is terminated normally. The problem was just switching tab from crtexe.c to main.c doesn't work automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image I see the call before the condition:

```
mainret = main(argc, argv);
```

You declared the main function:

```
int main();
```

Since the program was successfully linked the program is in C language. Thus the stack frame is corrupted after `main` exited. On Windows it is a default call convention that callee function is responsible for cleaning up function arguments from the stack and caller gets invalid stack frame (stack register) after `main`. You should declare main function properly:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv);
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed `main()` like this and now it works fine.